# Cast to string failed

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have this model

```
var PostSchema = new Schema({
    username: {type: String},
    message:  {type: String}
});
```

and i am trying save one custom record

```
var p = new Post({username: "wow", message:"Hello, world!"});
    p.save(function(err, p) {
        if (err) return console.error(err);
        console.log(p);
    });
```

but getting error

```
  message: 'Post validation failed',
  name: 'ValidationError',
  errors: 
   { username: 
      { message: 'Cast to String failed for value "wow" at path "username"',
        name: 'CastError',
        kind: 'String',
        value: 'wow',
        path: 'username' } } }
```

Comment: this code looks fine to me. my only guess is that you have extra code leftover thats causing this error somewhere.